# Counting characters after a specific point in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a bunch of strings in a file that look like this:

```
|first string|the second string of interest
```

I would like to count the number of characters that start after second pipe, which in this case is 29. Would appreciate any help

Comment: You have to count characters _after the last occurrency of a certain character_? Is it correct?

Comment: I guess that is what I am trying to do!

Comment: Is the second pipe always the last one? If not, you should clarify which rule we should follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
 string.split('|').last.length
```

Comment: not accurate if the second string of interest also includes the pipe symbol

Comment: @cache.zero - not according to the comments under the question

Comment: @cache.zero - agree, however there are always only two pipes on each line

Answer (score 1):

```
string[/(?<=\|)[^|]*\z/].length
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regexp would be most flexible, here you could do

```
string.match(/\|.*\|(.*)/)[1].length
=> 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Advanced regex: positive lookbehind + negative lookahead:

```
match = '|first string|the second string of interest'[/(?<=\|)(?!.*\|).*/]
#=> "the second string of interest"
match.size #=> 29
```